# Targeting an element with value in data tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to target the following line via tha data tag `data-filter`

```
<a href="?filter=open" class="list-group-item" data-filter="open">Open</a>
```

I've used the following code but it does not work:

```
$('[data-filter]="open"').addClass('active');
```

I am getting the following error in the console:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-filter]="open"

Comment: Selector should be like this `$('[data-filter="open"]').addClass('active');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the attribute selector with the correct syntax:

```
$('[data-filter="open"]').addClass('active');
```

Or you can use the *much* faster `filter`:

```
$('.list-group-item').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('filter') == 'open';
}).addClass('active');
```

Comment: I think `$('.list-group-item[data-filter="open"]')` will be faster

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Could you explain why your suggestion would be faster?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `[data-filter="open"]`. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp.

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools to back up your answers. W3Schools is terrible. Besides the jQuery API documentation is the definitive reference.

Comment: I'm not a fan of W3Schools either, but in this case I wanted to point out that the selector is just the plain CSS3 selector, that jQuery simply accepted in its selector system. As to jQuery docs, here it is: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/